Simple recursive sum when compiled from Haskell to WASM is quadratic
The following Haskell funcion:
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Data.Word (Word32)

sum' :: Word32 -> Word32
sum' 0 = 0
sum' n = n + sum' (n-1)

foreign export javascript "sum" sum' :: Word32 -> Word32

main :: IO ()
main = print (sum' 10000000)

When compiled to WASM is quadratic on n, instead of linear, as expected. Because of that, it is millions of times slower than the native version, which isn't expected for WASM. Is this a compiler bug, or am I doing something wrong?
I'm using GHC 9.11.20240817, with the following command:
wasm32-wasi-ghc main.hs -O2 -no-hs-main -optl-mexec-model=reactor

Followed by the post-linking step:
$(wasm32-wasi-ghc --print-libdir)/post-link.mjs -i main.wasm -o main.js

I'm then importing sum from JS and calling it on different n's.

It's quadratic in GHC's native code gen, too, when you consider GC cost as the list grows. It's possible the WASM runtime just doesn't give you enough heap space to paper over that the way you usually can with native code.

@Carl What list? Are you sure about your "quadratic" assertion? I would very much expect this to be O(n) or even O(1) depending on how aggressive the optimizer has gotten.

@DanielWagner unless GHC rewrites it to a left fold (equivalent), it's keeping all those Word32s someplace. I guess it could be unboxed on the stack, but they need to be kept somewhere that's traversed every time the GC runs.

@Carl My mistake, you're right and I was just being lazy in my reasoning. Whoops!

For clarity: are you open to writing different Haskell to get better performance? Or do you demand that an answer cover a way to make the compiler smart enough to handle the code as-is?

@DanielWagner no for this question it isn't about making this specific program faster, but more about understanding the behavior, since it defies my expectations (that this should be linear)

Is it possible you've mistaken quadratic performance for "no performance"?  In my testing with version 9.11.20240818, I'm seeing linear performance up to sum' 258690872 and then non-termination from sum' 258690873 onward when compiling as a command module and running under wasmtime.  Specifically, if I compile:
module Main where

import Data.Word (Word32)

sum' :: Word32 -> Word32
sum' 0 = 0
sum' n = n + sum' (n-1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ sum' 258690872

with wasm32-wasi-ghc -O2 Sum.hs and run it with the wasmtime runtime, it runs in about 7 seconds.  If I increase 258690872 to 258690873 it doesn't terminate.
It looks like it's related to bad stack overflow handling, since playing with the RTS -K option, I can get sum' 258690872 to terminate with a stack overflow error, hang indefinitely, or complete in about 7 seconds, as the stack size is increased.
I've filed issue #25213.
